# How to select an specific element by a css class, but not other elements?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

So I want to select the `<div>` element with the class `.thisClass`, but not any other elements with class of `.thisClass`:

```
<div class="thisClass"></div>
<p class="thisClass"></p>
```

Answer (score 4):

[CSS Selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Getting_started/Selectors) by class name and tag: `div.thisClass { ... }`:

```css
div.thisClass {
    background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="thisClass">thisClass (div)</div>
<p class="thisClass">thisClass (p)</p>
```

But this is a [bad way to write selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Writing_efficient_CSS):

> **Don’t qualify class rules with tag names**
>
> The previous concept also applies here.  Though classes can be used many times on the same page, they are still more unique than a tag.
>
> One convention you can use is to include the tag name *in* the class name.  However, this may cost some flexibility; if design changes are made to the tag, the class names must be changed as well.  (It’s best to choose strictly semantic names, as such flexibility is one of the aims of separate stylesheets.)
>
> **BAD**
>   `treecell.indented {…}`
>
> **GOOD**
>   `.treecell-indented {…}`
>
> **BEST**
>   `.hierarchy-deep {…}`

Comment: Please keep in mind that the linked page [Writing efficient CSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Writing_efficient_CSS) is 15+ years old and much of the selector and combinator inefficiency has been improved

Comment: @andyb I didn't say about performance. This principle is actual now (to choose strictly semantic names), see [BEM methodology](http://getbem.com) for example.

Comment: Yes I know about BEM but performance _is related to_ the selector and is called out immediately after the section your answer quoted - "Use the most specific category possible". I mainly wanted to highlight that not all of the parts of the linked page are still relevant but I agree that your answer does not mention about performance and my comment was misleading.

Comment: @andyb thanks, now I understand your point. You are right about the other parts of the article.

Answer (score 2):

Using JavaScript

```
document.querySelector('div.thisClass')
```

Using jQuery

```
$("div.thisClass")
```

Using CSS:

```
<style>
    div.thisClass{}
</style>
```

Comment: @SverriM.Olsen sorry but can you explain it what do you mean by with mouse?

Comment: With the small comment that this will select all the divs with thisClass, if there's more than one on your page.

Comment: Why deliberately cloud the answer with so much irrelevant information? The only part of this that's relevant is the "Using CSS" portion but I have to skip *two* whole code snippets in order to find the relevant portion. Why make it more difficult for readers to find the answer than it already is? (And I'd bet that's the same point @Sverri M. Olsen is trying to make.)

Comment: @tomwrong: You should have rejected that edit as vandalism instead of approving it only to roll it back. Now the user has been rewarded +2 rep for essentially vandalising someone else's answer. (I see the <style> tags but they really aren't necessary.)

Comment: @BoltClock Point taken, I'm pretty new to reviewing changes.

Answer (score -1):

The following code illustrates how to select the first class from the list of classes in both CSS and Javascript.

**CSS**

```
.thisClass:first-child {
  /*css property*/
}
```

**JAVASCRIPT:**

```
var divElement = document.getElementsByClassName('thisClass')[0];
```

Comment: The CSS selector you're using is liable not to work because there is quite possibly other elements before these two. Also, the JS solution was not requested

Comment: Since the complete HTML wasn't given, it is assumed that there is no preceding element with the same class. This solution has been given after testing. I agree, that JavaScript solution wasn't required, but it has only been added post CSS solution.